# sklearn modules on Ubuntu / Oracle Virtual Box throw error

Tags: python, ubuntu, scikit-learn, conda

I get an `undefined symbol:` error message on some scikit-learn modules. The full error message is

```
ImportError: /home/<user>/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/
site-packages/sklearn/svm/libsvm.cpython-36m-i386-linux-gnu.so: 
undefined symbol: __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length
```

This happens not on the main package, `import sklearn` works w/o error. However, loading modules like

```
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import cluster
...
```

fails.
My system detail:

Host running Oracle Virtual Box 5.1.14 on Windows 10, 64 bit. Within VB, I am working on Ubuntu 16.10, 32 bit (32 instead of 64 bit in order to run TensorFlow) and installed Python 3.6 via Anaconda. `conda list` gives me `scikit-learn              0.18.1              np111py36_1` is installed.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7869 and update if this fixes for you.

Comment: Many thanks for the link. I chose not to update in the end, as this usually bears updating a lot of dependencies as well. I think it was quicker terminating the VM with Ubuntu 16.10 and setting up a fresh one with Ubuntu 16.04. Having done so, it works nicely. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, then please consider closing the question.

Comment: Problem is that anaconda comes packed with its own libgcc. An a very old version too. Just do "conda install libgcc" to upgrade (to something like  5.2).